# Converting a normal File to FormFile in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, memorystream, iformfile

So i want to convert a normal file to FormFile,i know that you can set the content type in a typical form,but i'm not sure how should i do that when i get a file from let's say from my storage and then convert that to FormFile.

A Couple of tutorials say that we have to convert it into Stream,which i've done but after that i'm just blank,any inputs would be helpfull

```
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream fileStream;
        using (fileStream = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
```

Comment: Would you like to add what you would like to do with the IFormFile?

Comment: @JsonDork Upload/Download operation

Comment: Do you want to upload file? You could try to use [FileUploaderPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin).

Comment: @Billy I need to leverage FormFile to do that,i mean its a requirement